# Quiero convertir todos los espacios en blanco de una frase que introduzca en asteriscos

Tags: c

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tiene que ser algo así... es en C.
Con los #include <stdio.h> y <string.h> bucles y la funcion strlen.
Gracias!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Partiendo de una frase:

```
char frase [] = "La casa   es  muy  grande  .";
```

Lo que tendríamos que hacer seria recorrer dicha frase utilizando un bucle `for` con la función [strlen()](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strlen) de la cabecera `<string.h>`

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(frase); i++)
```

Después comprobar que en la posición en la que estamos de la frase es un espacio en blanco

`' '` y sustituirlo por `*`

```
 if(frase[i]== ' ')
        frase[i] = '*';
```

Finalmente mostrar la frase resultante:

```
printf("%s",frase);
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char frase [] = "La casa   es  muy  grande  .";

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(frase); i++){
        if(frase[i]== ' ')
            frase[i] = '*';        
    }

    printf("%s",frase);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias bro!

Comment: @grefusaa si te ha servido mi respuesta, vota positivo y marca como aceptada con el check gris.

Answer (score -1):

Debes utilizar replace [Ejemplo C#]

```
String s = "a a a ";
Console.WriteLine("The initial string: '{0}'", s);
s = s.Replace(" ", "*");
Console.WriteLine("The final string: '{0}'", s);

// The example displays the following output:
//       The initial string: 'a a a '
//       The final string: 'a*a*a*'
```

Ejemplo sólo con C

```
// C program to search and replace 
// all occurrences of a word with 
// other word. 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

// Function to replace a string with another 
// string 
char* replaceWord(const char* s, const char* oldW, 
                const char* newW) 
{ 
    char* result; 
    int i, cnt = 0; 
    int newWlen = strlen(newW); 
    int oldWlen = strlen(oldW); 

    // Counting the number of times old word 
    // occur in the string 
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) { 
        if (strstr(&s[i], oldW) == &s[i]) { 
            cnt++; 

            // Jumping to index after the old word. 
            i += oldWlen - 1; 
        } 
    } 

    // Making new string of enough length 
    result = (char*)malloc(i + cnt * (newWlen - oldWlen) + 1); 

    i = 0; 
    while (*s) { 
        // compare the substring with the result 
        if (strstr(s, oldW) == s) { 
            strcpy(&result[i], newW); 
            i += newWlen; 
            s += oldWlen; 
        } 
        else
            result[i++] = *s++; 
    } 

    result[i] = '\0'; 
    return result; 
} 

// Driver Program 
int main() 
{ 
    char str[] = "a a a "; 
    char c[] = " "; 
    char d[] = "*"; 

    char* result = NULL; 

    // oldW string 
    printf("Old string: %s\n", str); 

    result = replaceWord(str, c, d); 
    printf("New String: %s\n", result); 

    free(result); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, pero el problema se pide en lenguaje C y no en C#

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Por favor, si te ha servido, no olvides votar positiva la respuesta y marcar como correcta en el caso de ser la implementación utilizada, un saludo